# Statistic of choice?

Tags: probability, statistics, mathematical-modeling

I am not good at maths. So, don't mind if it is silly. Suppose we have a mode choice of transport given - as such as people  who take

- bike - 1%
- car - 45%
- Walk- 54%
  This is the representation of the population of 20,000 people.

Now, suppose, I want to translate this choice to 20 people. Will it be the same (1, 45, 54%)? and how do I check if it's right If there are 20 new people every time for 100 iterations?

Comment: Hmm... if I understand your question, I think this is to do with Statistical Inference. The problem is - if you pick ${20}$ people out of the ${20,000}$ people - how do you know you've not just accidentally happened to picked ${20}$ people that all walk? So then you'd observe the percentages ${(0,0,100)}$. It's a very difficult problem to deal with, since you usually want to be able to make general remarks about a population with only limited samples. There's a lot of techniques, but you can never be ${100\%}$ certain

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, how do we approximate? Is there a way?

Comment: indeed! There are methods to do so. BruceET has written up a nice answer to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sampling.** Suppose that the true proportions in categories B, C, W of a population are $0.01, 0.45, 0.54,$ respectively.

Then if you take a huge random sample of size $n = 20,000$ from the population, you might get the counts below. (Sampling and computations in R.)

```
set.seed(810)
huge = sample(1:3, 20000, rep=T, c(.01,.45,.54))
table(huge)
huge
    1     2     3 
  198  9066 10736
```

Then corresponding proportions would be
$0.0099, 0.4533, 0.5368,$ which are very close
to the population proportions $0.01, 0.45, 0.54.$
(Discrepancies seem like rounding errors.)

```
table(huge)/20000
huge
     1      2      3 
0.0099 0.4533 0.5368
```

However, if I take a tiny sample of only size 20, then
I will not get proportions so close to the true
population proportions.

```
set.seed(811)
tiny = sample(1:3, 20, rep=T, c(.01,.45,.54))
table(tiny)
tiny
 1  2  3 
 1  7 12 
table(tiny)/20
tiny
   1    2    3 
0.05 0.35 0.60
```

**Testing.** By contrast, a question can arise in research about the validity
of a hypothetical population proportion, perhaps arising
from theory about human behavior or from a supposition
that behavior has not changed since the last large survey
was done ten years ago.

From whatever source suppose our null hypothesis is
that the population proportions are $0.01, 0.45, 0.54.$
A take a moderate-sized random sample of size $n = 200.$
And I get counts, $5, 100, 65.$

The proportions don't agree exactly with the hypothesis.
The question is whether the disagreement is sufficiently
large to reject the null hypothesis as untrue, or whether
random sampling error can account for the discrepancy.

***Oberved and expected counts.*** I will compare by observed counts with the expected
counts according to the null hypothesis. I get the expected counts by multiplying the sample size 200 by the hypothetical population proportions. (I happen to get
integers here, but expected counts should *not* be rounded
to integers if they're not integers.)

```
       B   C   W   Tot
Obs    5 100  95   200
Exp    2  90 108   200
```

***Test statistic.*** In a chi-squared test, the chi-squared statistic is
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^K \frac{(X_i = E_i)^2}{E_i},$$
where $K$ is the number of categories, $X_i$ are the
observed counts and $E_i$ are the corresponding expected
counts. For our data $Q = 7.18.$

```
X = c(5, 100, 95)
E = 200 * c(.01, .45, .54)
Q = sum((X-E)^2/E);  Q
[1] 7.175926
```

***Distribution of test statistic.*** Provided that all of the $E_i > 5,$ we have
$Q \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(2),$ the chi-squared
distribution with $K-1 = 2$ degrees of freedom.

***Critical value.*** The critical value $c = 5.991$ for a test at the 5% level
is the value that cuts 5% of the probability from
the upper tail of this distribution. [You can find
this value in printed tables of chi-squared distributions,
or by using software, as below.]

```
qchisq(.95, 2)
[1] 5.991465
```

Because we have $Q = 7.18 > 5.99,$ we reject the null
hypothesis. We say that the counts we observed are not
consistent with the null hypothesis.

***P-value.*** Another way to test the null hypothesis is to get the P-value. It is the probability of a more extreme result
than observed. Specifically, it is $P(Q \ge 7.18),$
computed using $A \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(2).$ For our
test, the P-value is $0.276 < 0.05 = 5\%,$ so we can
use the P-value to reject the null hypothesis.

```
1 - pchisq(7.18, 2)
[1] 0.02759833
```

You usually can't get exact P-values from printed chi-squared tables. But you may be able to see from tables
that the P-value is between 0.01 and 0.05. Statistical
software usually gives a P-value as part of the output
from the test procedure.

The plot below shows the density function of
$\mathsf{Chisq}(2).$ The vertical red dotted line shows
the critical value, and the vertical black line show
the value of the test statistic. The area under the density curve to the right of the red line is 5%' the area to the right of the black line is the P-value.

[image]

**Chi-squared test in R.** Below is output from the procedure `chisq.test` in R. (It differs slightly from results above because of differences in rounding.)

```
chisq.test(X, p=c(.01,.45,.54))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  X
```

X-squared = 7.1759, df = 2, p-value = 0.02765

There is a warning message that the P-value may not be exactly
correct. One of our expected counts is $2$ not $> 5,$
so $Q$ might not have exactly the distribution
$\mathsf{Chisq}(2).$ Many textbooks say it is OK if
most of the $E_i > 5$ and all $E_i > 3.$ So we should have used a slightly larger sample.

In such cases, the `chisq.test` in R can simulate
the the P-value. Abbreviated output is shown below:

```
chisq.test(X, p=c(.01,.45,.54), simulate=T)$p.val
[1] 0.03448276
```

There seems
no doubt we can reject at the 5% level.

Comment: Thank you BruceET. That is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you like it. Let me know if you have questions about this kind of test. Bedtime now. Will look tomorrow.

Comment: I have created a qualitative model that showcases mode choices for people in an area. Qualitative in the sense it is based on people's preference. The population of the area is about 20,000. I have a real survey. that shows the value ((1, 45, 54%). But the problem is my model can only consider 20 people in one iteration because of computational limitation. So, everytime, i run the model. i have mixed results. That is why i wanted to validate my model. So how do i translate your answer into my work? sorry, statistics is hard for me !

Comment: 20 observations is too small a sample to expect to declare as significant small disagreements of sample proportions with population proportions. Also too small for traditional chi-sq test; simulation in R makes the test valid, but does not make finding significant differences easier. // The 1% for bicycle use category is especially problematic. May have better luck by combing categories B & W. Then you can do an exact binomial test. Still. 20 is too small to have good power to detect differences from hypothetical model.

Comment: Then what would be the minimal observation needed if so?

Comment: If Bike at 1% is to be a separate category you may need 300 subjects overall in order to get the expected count for that category over 3. But in R you can use simulation to get a reliable P-value and the requirements for simulation to work well are not so easy to specify. Trial and error, maybe.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will check it out